# Formatting Unix password store ls output

Tags: bash, sed, replace, grep

I just want to automate some process, and I need to be able to format the output from `pass ls`

Which is the listing command for https://www.passwordstore.org

Current output looks like so:

```
➜  ~ pass ls
Password Store
├── README.md
├── folder
│   └── subfolder
│       └── subfolder2
│           └── key1
│           └── key2
│           └── key3
├── anotherfolder
│   ├── subfolder
│   │   └── subfolder2
│   │       └── subfolder3
│   │           └── key1
│   │           └── key2
│   │           └── key3
```

I want the output to look like:

```
 ➜  ~ pass ls | some magic sed/grep/replace/etc
folder/subfolder/subfolder2/key1
folder/subfolder/subfolder2/key2
folder/subfolder/subfolder2/key3
anotherfolder/subfolder/subfolder2/subfolder3/key1
anotherfolder/subfolder/subfolder2/subfolder3/key2
anotherfolder/subfolder/subfolder2/subfolder3/key3
```

I am trying to use `sed` to do so, but couldn't replace the increasing spaces/tabs as the subfolder levels gets deeper (for example folder/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/key)

Here is what I am trying so far:

```
pass ls | sed -e 's/├──[ \t]*/\\/g' | sed -e 's/│   └──[ \t]*/\\/g'
```

**EDIT AFTER COMMENTS:**

Seems like `pass ls` is just a simple `tree` command on the password store directory, so I can run `find` on my directory to achieve the above format I want

I will try that, and the scope of the question can be changed to:

**What's the proper listing command that can produce the above format?**

Comment: Honestly, wouldn't it be less fiddly and more robust to patch `pass` itself to have an output format designed to be easy-to-parse (JSON or such) as an option? Then you wouldn't need to worry about a future version changing the formatting slightly and breaking your logic unintentionally.

Comment: The documentation says it uses `tree(1)` for formatting, which I think implies there is a directory somewhere that you could theoretically use `find` on. (That directory may be a short-lived temporary file system internal to `pass`, in which case `pass` itself would need to provide the interface.)

Comment: Hmm. If it finds `tree` through a PATH lookup, that makes it easy to override, temporarily putting your own version of `tree` that runs `find` instead first in the PATH for the duration of the run...

Comment: I'm surprised that `pass` doesn't already provide such output, given its claim to following the Unix philosophy.

Comment: Are that `|` not on behind every subfolder?  Isn't it `│   │   │    └── subfolder3` instead of `│   │        └── subfolder3`? Also `└── key1` shouldn't it be `├── key1`? Is another `subfolder` in `anortherfolder` missing? And yet another root folder is missing from the tool ouptut? Is this the actual real output from the tool or some preprocessed example? Please post the actual real output from the tool - it _matters_ a lot when writing a parser of it..

Comment: Yep I was also just thinking of the `tree` approach
@chepner yes I was also very disappointed about that, and tried to go through the man page many times to find something about formatting

Comment: Ah found that `pass ls` is just doing a `tree`command on my password store folder, so no magic here, then if I can format the output of the `tree` command or just use another command to listing like `find`, that would do the trick

Comment: Oh, I misread how `pass` worked; I was thinking the whole store was a single GPG file. I bet you can just do something like `find <yourdirectory> -type f`, without using `pass` at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type d -name '.git' -prune -o -name '*.gpg' -type f -print
```

Did the trick for me, it excludes all files in `.git` directory, and only prints files with `.gpg` extension (which are the actual keys)

Comment: It looks like you could wrap this up in a shell script to turn into a `pass` [extension](https://www.passwordstore.org/#extensions).